# search for django-objects tagged with all tags in a set

Tags: sql, django, filter

In my django-project have a search function where you can specify tags, like "apple, banana" and by that query for objects of a certain model, tagged with `taggit`. When I do:

```
tag_set = Tag.objects.filter(Q(name__in=tag_list))
query_set = Model.objects.filter(Q(tags__in=tag_set))
```

this gives me objects tagged with either "apple" OR "banana". But I want the AND operator... I tried:

```
query_set = Model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(tags__in=x) for x in tag_set)))
```

but then I get `'Tag' object is not iterable`.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with:

```
queryset = Model.objects.all()
for tag in tag_list:
    queryset = queryset.filter(tags__name=tag)
```

This will make a `JOIN` for each tag, and thus eventually the `queryset` will only contain `Model` items that have all the necessary tags.

Another approach is counting the number of matched tags, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

tag_set = set(tag_list)
Model.objects.filter(tag__name__in=tag_set).alias(
    ntags=Count('tags')
).filter(ntags=len(tag_set))
```